# Sort Properties in an Object Initializer with ReSharper or Built-In IDE Features

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

Given the following code:

```
var x = new myObject() {
  prop3 = 8,
  prop1 = 5,
  prop2 = 6
}
```

Ideally, I would like to use ReSharper or built-in IDE features to sort the properties above so that they appear like this:

```
var x = new myObject() {  
  prop1 = 5,
  prop2 = 6,
  prop3 = 8
}
```

Outside of that, I'd be open to a lightweight extension--CodeMaid was way too heavy and overlaps with too many ReSharper functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in feature in Visual Studio for this:

1. Select all properties.
2. Edit > Advanced > Sort Lines

Each assignment has to be on one single line though.

Comment: Unfortunately, this sorts the properties in alphabetical order. I thought you could manually decide how to sort them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with ReSharper but if all your properties are on separate lines then you could use the [CodeMaid](http://www.codemaid.net/) extension and use its Sort Lines functionality (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>,<kbd>F9</kbd>) - You would need to fix the commas as it is just a text sort and doesn't have any understanding of syntax.

Comment: Hmm, didn't know about CodeMaid, so thanks. Might try that (I try to avoid installing additional extensions onto the IDE)--still would like to see a ReSharper solution.

Comment: 2½ years later, has anyone found a solution for this? Has it been added to Resharper?

Comment: @Milton Yes, see my answer.