# Possibility to rearrange properties in object initializer

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper, object-initializers

I would like to **rearrange** my properties inside a `object initializer`, by manually defining the new position. I found this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40743021/sort-properties-in-an-object-initializer-with-resharper-or-built-in-ide-features) but the first method only sorts the properties alphabetically, the other uses a different extension method.

```
new Student { StudentID = 2, Nationality = Nationalities.Austrian, StudentName = "Peter", Age = 21 }
```

A line like the above, I would like to rearrange **using ReSharper or a Built-In Feature** to this:

```
new Student { StudentID = 2, StudentName = "Peter", Age = 21,  Nationality = Nationalities.Austrian }
```

Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Comment: How would you define the order? What do you gain by doing this? I don't think there is any way to do this as far as I know.

Comment: By having a refactoring option, you could be able to do so. For example in ReSharper you can change position of your parameters in the Method. Obviously this approach is really needed, but I thought maybe it's also possible for object initializer.